# How can I fix EXM 3.3 upgrade causing message view to fail and be mostly blank?

Tags: upgrade, exm

We are working on upgrading to EXM 3.3 from 3.2.  On my local sandbox, after performing the upgrade, everything appears to be good except for the fact that when I go to view a message from the manager screen, the page that loads is mostly blank displaying only the Back arrow button, empty drop down, language drop down, Save button and the Email campaign info label and table.

All of the javascript and css files referenced by the `/root/sitecore/client/Applications/ECM/Pages/Messages/Subscription?id=[guid]&sc_speakcontentlang=en` appear to load correctly, however, I do see this error in the javascript console:

`GlobalValidationService.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Validation.create is not a function(…)(anonymous function) @ GlobalValidationService.js:2execCb @ require.js:1650check @ require.js:866(anonymous function) @ require.js:1113(anonymous function) @ require.js:132(anonymous function) @ require.js:1156each @ require.js:57emit @ require.js:1155check @ require.js:917enable @ require.js:1143init @ require.js:774callGetModule @ require.js:1170completeLoad @ require.js:1544onScriptLoad @ require.js:1671`

[image: EXM 3.2 Empty Message View]

We have checked the log files and have not been able to find anything pertaining to this issue.

**Environment Details:**

Sitecore 8.1 (rev. 160519)

**Additional Notes:**

When a new Sitecore instance is installed with EXM 3.3, it works until we sync and publish our Sitecore content and our Visual Studio project.  However, deleting our custom assets (js, css files) doesn't appear to affect any change.

This problem appears to affect both pre-existing e-mails AND e-mails created after the upgrade.

**UPDATE:**

After the suggestions, I have tried copying all of the files in /sitecore and /sitecore_modules out of the package and into the site and it does not fix the problem.

Comment: What Sitecore version are you on?

Comment: I updated the post to answer your question @DmytroShevchenko

Comment: When you log out of Sitecore, and log back in, and go directly to EXM to view a message, does it work then?

Comment: @PeteNavarra I logged out, logged back in, chose Email Experience Manager from the launchpad.  I then see the main EXM screen with the reports.  I click on Drafts and then click on my email that loads and that is when I see the blank Message view.

Comment: Go into Content Editor, go to the message you are looking for, and look at the Message Type field and see if it's "Ad-hoc" with a [Item not found] messages or blank.

Comment: When I originally looked at that field, it was set to "Subscription" under  "Items not in selection list", but after changing it to the new "Subscription Message" type, the problem persists.

Comment: For that screen that you are trying to get to, the message type should be "One Time Message".

Comment: Actually, one more question... the other field that matters is the Status field. What is that field set to?

Comment: @PeteNavarra It was originally a subscription so shouldn't be a subscription message in the new version?  Also, I couldn't find a "Status" field.  I found a "State" field under the System group that was set to Draft, but I couldn't find a "Status" field under any of the groupings for the item.  The message item inherits from a custom Daily Digest template that inherits from the template "A/B Testable Message".  I hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I'm so stuck on issues with EXM, I'm not realizing your additional info.  Based on what you're saying, sounds like there a bootstrap or jquery conflict. EXM screens are completely built by SPEAKUI, which requires specific versions on JS and other modules. If it's breaking after publishing your VS solution, I'm thinking it might be JS conflict.

Comment: That's kind of what I thought but all of the referenced assets by the page loads and they are all base sitecore exm files.  It's possible that maybe the upgrade didn't upgrade one of these files when it should have but I have no idea how to find which one is wrong and aside from the javascript error, I have no errors to tell me what the problem file is.

Comment: Aaron, it looks like some Javascript files didn't get applied when you upgraded. Can you try installing a blank 8.1 u3 with EXM 3.3 and compare the files? I think you're missing \sitecore\shell\client\Applications\ECM\EmailCampaign.Client\Component\Validation\Validation.js

Comment: @JacobNielsen Please see update.  I have checked and that Validation.js file is there and now I am sure that all of those assets are from the upgraded EXM package.

Comment: What's the output of http://<HOSTNAME>/-/speak/v1/ecm/GlobalValidationService.js and http://<HOSTNAME>/-/speak/v1/ecm/Validation.js ?

Comment: That Validation.js is from EXM 3.2. You probably have a Validation.js in both the /sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ECM/EmailCampaign.Client/Component/ folder and the /sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ECM/EmailCampaign.Client/Component/Validation/ folder. You should be able to delete the former, but you might have other leftovers

Comment: @JacobNielsen So, you were correct that I had Validation.js file in both places.  I removed it from the former location as you have suggested and received a 404 when the browser attempted to retrieve that file.  However, copying the one from the /Validation folder and putting it into the /Component folder seems to have fixed the issue.  My only concern now is that it seems to be looking in the wrong place for that since the new stuff is in the /Validation folder.  Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of changes was made to the EXM UI between 3.2 and 3.3. Your problem is that the Validation.js was moved from the /sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ECM/EmailCampaign.Client‌​/Component/ folder to the /sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ECM/EmailCampaign.Client/Component/Validation folder.

These changes should have been automatically applied during the upgrade (I'm looking at the 3.2 -> 3.3 upgrade package right now, and the definitions are correct), so for some reason your upgrade didn't make all of the changes. You can pretty easily fix this problem by removing the old Validation.js and adding the new Validation.js, but I'd be vary of doing that without fully understanding what other (if any) changes have not been applied. I suggest creating a clean EXM 3.3 install and diff'ing with your upgrade installation, looking for any differences.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  That just saved us so much time and trouble!!

Comment: Yes, thank you!  I was able to resolve the issue by deleting the relevant folders inside the /sitecore and /sitecore_modules folders and installed the full 3.3 package over my local web site instance which resolved this issue completely.  With some additional massaging, I was able to get everything working and update the necessary files in the project to the updated ones (and remove some that were removed).